# How to prevent blank fields using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using this to check if fields are empty.  The problem is, the error message is never thrown when a field is empty, it allows submission.  Is it because I am trying to run `onclick` and `onclientclick` on the button?  This is my syntax

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="main1212" runat="server" Text="Check If JS Works" 
OnClick="DoSomethingDoNothing_OnClick" OnClientClick="return ValidateData();" />
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateData() {
    var main1212, dropdownselection, dropdownselection1, field21
    main1212 = document.getElementByID("txt313").value;
    dropdownselection = document.getElementByID("dropdownlist1").value;
    dropdownselection1 = document.getElementByID("dropdownlist11").value;
    field21 = document.getElementByID("txt12").value; 
    if (main1212 == '')
    {
        alert("Error");
        return false;
    }
    if (dropdownselection == '')
    {
        alert("Error");
        return false;
    }
    if (dropdownlist1 == '')
    {
        alert("Error")
        return false;
    }
    if (field21 == '')
    {
        alert("Error");
        return false;
    }}
</script>
```

**EDIT**
If I open the browser console and press the button that should run my script their are no errors displayed?

Comment: What is your JavaScript doing? Are you sure it runs? Which path through the code does it take? Learn to debug your code (step through it line by line, inspecting the values).

Comment: If you open your web console, you'll see an error telling you what's wrong: The `D` in `getElementByID` should be lower case. Always, always, always open the web console if your code is doing something unexpected and look for errors. Also use the powerful debugger built into your browser to watch the code run line-by-line.

Comment: @mason - none of the alerts are fired.  I will google to learn how to log to console and see if that will show me where my issue is....

Comment: Side note: If you want a field with a space in it to be considered "empty," you'll need to update your check. Most modern JavaScript engines now have `String#trim`, but for older ones, you can shim it.

Comment: How and where are you declaring your other controls txt313, dropdownlist1... In a parent server control? Are they with ClientIDMode = Static? if not then you can try accessing them as `getElementById('<%= txt313.ClientID%>')`

Comment: @haraman - they are being declared within div tags similar to how the asp:button is created

Comment: @MustangLover Try to use server control reference mode as mentioned in my previous comment. If the problem persists then edit your post to include how you are declaring txt and ddl controls and if they are inside any other server control such GridView, FormView, Repeater etc.

Comment: @MustangLover you should also find a tutorial on javascript form validation like this one: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp Step 1 in learning is tutorials, you will eventually move past this phase but skipping it would be unecessary torture. Also look here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing a semi-colon in this line (not sure) of the function *ValidateData*:

```
var main1212,dropdownselection,dropdownselection1,field21;
```

(it's good to avoid extra spaces and also not create variables for this)

And it could be more simple, or like this:

```
window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('main1212').onclick=function(){ValidateData();};}
```

Comment: By refereing a comma and point you mean to say `;` (a semi colon) after `field21;`

Comment: Correcting that and the comment by @T.J. Crowder of making the 'd' lowercase it is working.